# Generating Position Vectors from Numpy Meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'll try to explain my issue here without going into too much detail on the actual application so that we can stay grounded in the code. Basically, I need to do operations to a vector field. My first step is to generate the field as

`x,y,z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5,5,10),np.linspace(-5,5,10),np.linspace(-5,5,10))`

Keep in mind that this is a generalized case, in the program, the bounds of the vector field are not all the same. In the general run of things, I would expect to say something along the lines of

`u,v,w = f(x,y,z)`.

Unfortunately, this case requires so more difficult operations. I need to use a formula similar to

[image: Simplified version of Biot Savart Equation]  where the vector r is defined in the program as `np.array([xgrid-x,ygrid-y,zgrid-z])` divided by its own norm. Basically, this is a vector pointing from every point in space to the position (x,y,z)

Now Numpy has implemented a cross product function using `np.cross()`, but I can't seem to create a "meshgrid of vectors" like I need. 
I have a lambda function that is essentially

`xgrid,ygrid,zgrid=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5,5,10),np.linspace(-5,5,10),np.linspace(-5,5,10))
B(x,y,z) = lambda x,y,z: np.cross(v,np.array([xgrid-x,ygrid-y,zgrid-z]))`

Now the array `v` is imported from another class and seems to work just fine, but the second array, `np.array([xgrid-x,ygrid-y,zgrid-z])` is not a proper shape because it is a "vector of meshgrids" instead of a "meshgrid of vectors". My big issue is that I cannot seem to find a method by which to format the meshgrid in such a way that the `np.cross()` function can use the position vector. Is there a way to do this?

Originally I thought that I could do something along the lines of:

`x,y,z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2,2,5),np.linspace(-2,2,5),np.linspace(-2,2,5))
A = np.array([x,y,z])
cross_result = np.cross(np.array(v),A)`

This, however, returns the following error, which I cannot seem to circumvent:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1682, in cross
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: incompatible dimensions for cross product
(dimension must be 2 or 3)`

Comment: Can you post some more representative formula (`x`,`y` and `z` don't appear in it right now) and some example data and desired output?

Comment: Using `X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)`, I feel like `A = np.array([X, Y, Z ])` gives you an array of position vectors. This can be fed directly to `np.cross`, and you can specify along which are axis the coordinates are using `axisa` or `axisb`.

Comment: I'm not totally following your question. Is `v` a fixed vector field associated to the volume defined by the grid `x,y,z`? And are you trying to compute `B(x,y,z)`?

Comment: @Liris, That was my initial intuition, but it gives the error that I have added above. My guess is that this produces an array of arrays, which numpy assumes is something like a 3x50 matrix that cannot be crossed.

Comment: @QuangHoang, Yes, in this case, `v` is the vector dl in the equation, which I have as a numpy array from a class in a different part of the program. The real issue is constructing the r vector because I need to create essentially a meshgrid of vectors pointing from the point `(x,y,z)` to any given point in the meshgrid.

Comment: @BooleanDesigns what do you have when do `print(v.shape)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, `v.shape = (3,)`

Answer (score 0):

There's a work around with `reshape` and broadcasting:

```
A = np.array([x_grid, y_grid, z_grid])
# A.shape == (3,5,5,5)

def B(v, p):
    '''
    v.shape = (3,)
    p.shape = (3,) 
    '''
    shape = A.shape

    Ap = A.reshape(3,-1) - p[:,None]

    return np.cross(v[None,:], Ap.reshape(3,-1).T).reshape(shape)

print(B(v,p).shape)
# (3, 5, 5, 5)
```

Comment: what is `p`? is `p` this position?

Comment: `p` is your reference point, i.e., `p= (x,y,z)` in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original attempt only lacks the specification of the axis along which the cross product should be executed.

```
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2, 2, 5),np.linspace(-2, 2, 5), np.linspace(-2, 2, 5))
A = np.array([x, y, z])
cross_result = np.cross(np.array(v), A, axis=0)
```

I tested this with the code below. As an alternative to `np.array([x, y, z])`, you can also use `np.stack(x, y, z, axis=0)`, which clearly shows along which axis the meshgrids are stacked to form a meshgrid of vectors, the vectors being aligned with axis 0. I also printed the shape each time and used random input for testing. In the test, the output of the formula is compared at a random index to the cross product of the input-vector at the same index with vector v.

```
import numpy as np 

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 10), np.linspace(-5, 5, 10), np.linspace(-5, 5, 10))
p = np.random.rand(3) # random reference point
A = np.array([x-p[0], y-p[1], z-p[2]]) # vectors from positions to reference
A_bis = np.stack((x-p[0], y-p[1], z-p[2]), axis=0) 
print(f"A equals A_bis? {np.allclose(A, A_bis)}") # the two methods of stacking yield the same

v = -1 + 2*np.random.rand(3) # random vector v

B = np.cross(v, A, axis=0) # cross-product for all points along correct axis
print(f"Shape of v: {v.shape}")
print(f"Shape of A: {A.shape}")
print(f"Shape of B: {B.shape}")


print("\nComparison for random locations: ")
point = np.random.randint(0, 9, 3) # generate random multi-index
a = A[:, point[0], point[1], point[2]] # look up input-vector corresponding to index
b = B[:, point[0], point[1], point[2]] # look up output-vector corresponding to index
print(f"A[:, {point[0]}, {point[1]}, {point[2]}] = {a}")
print(f"v = {v}")
print(f"Cross-product as v x a:         {np.cross(v, a)}")
print(f"Cross-product from B (= v x A): {b}")
```

The resulting output looks like:

```
A equals A_bis? True
Shape of v: (3,)
Shape of A: (3, 10, 10, 10)
Shape of B: (3, 10, 10, 10)

Comparison for random locations: 
A[:, 8, 1, 1] = [-4.03607312  3.72661831 -4.87453077]
v = [-0.90817859  0.10110274 -0.17848181]
Cross-product as v x a:         [ 0.17230515 -3.70657882 -2.97637688]
Cross-product from B (= v x A): [ 0.17230515 -3.70657882 -2.97637688]
```